# Snapping objects

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

Is there any other way to track objects than the following link?

[through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2013/12/disabling-snapping-to-specific-autocad-objects-using-net-part-2](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2013/12/disabling-snapping-to-specific-autocad-objects-using-net-part-2.html)

Does anyone know how to turn on / off snapping objects?

Are points stored in a collection that we can modify?

I want to do something similar in ZWCad and unfortunately Overrule is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk knowledge network shows you how to [get/set system variables](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-F6B3122D-A6F4-4112-A838-4662E0E1B30B-htm.html), you'll want to [edit the OSMODE](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-DD9B3216-A533-4D47-95D8-7585F738FD75-htm.html).

```
// Set system variable to new value
Application.SetSystemVariable("OSMODE", 0);
```